# Have function run at a particular time using python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to have a function run once at a particular time. I have used  My code is the following:

```
import pytz
import datetime
import time

def test_1():

    print("Working_1")


def test_2():

    print("Working_2")


while True:

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    if current_time == '2019-03-18T19:00:36Z':

        test_1()

        current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


        if current_time > '2019-03-18T19:00:36Z':

            break

        if current_time == '2019-03-18T19:00:36Z':

            test_2()


            current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


            if current_time > '2019-03-18T19:00:36Z':

                break
```

When I run my code it runs the first function followed by the second one until the end condition.

I want the function to run at the specified times in the `if` statement.

I think the problem is occurring about how loops are nested. I have tried multiple configurations of the `if` statement and break condition but just cannot get it.

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers.
Sandy

Comment: why is your code double-spaced..?

Comment: I just find it a bit easier to read.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? How did it not meet expectations?

Comment: I would like the functions to run at the times specified in the if statement. This should be changed to sompoint in the future.

Comment: All four of your `if` statements are comparing to the exact same time. From your post, I gather you intend things to happen at multiple different times. I'd start there.

Comment: Ah ok. I put the `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` in the if statement as I want this action to be done again and then compared in the next if statement.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not clear on why. (That is, I'm unsure what you want your code to do.) When, if ever, do you want `test_2()` executed?

Comment: If `current_time ` ==  `'2019-03-18T19:00:36Z'` I would like `test_1() ` to run once then when `current_time ` ==  `2019-03-18T19:00:36Z` I would like `test_2() ` to run once. Then after this the loop to be broken.

Comment: Aren't those both the same time, though?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code here doesn't work because it would require the time to be EXACTLY the timestamp given, and when accounting for run-time, even if minimal, this is quite unrealistic. A possible solution is to give a "time cushion", i.e a window around the execution time rather than an exact match for the if statement; however this is still quite unreliable.

If you don't mind using an external module, I would recommend you take a look at [sched](https://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) or [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.3/). I've personally used the latter, and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Taking my best guess at what you want: You want both functions to run, in order, at a particular time, yes? Something much simpler should work, like this:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
while current_time < '2019-03-18T19:00:36Z':
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
test_1()
test_2()
```

This will run both functions as soon as the clock hits or passes your target time.

**EDIT:** If you want them to run at two different times:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
while current_time < '<first_time>':
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
test_1()
while current_time < '<second_time>':
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
test_2()
```

(where `<first_time>` is first chronologically)

Comment: The current_time can be compared `'2019-03-18T18:35:36Z' > '2019-03-18T18:34:36Z'` returns true

Comment: What if I want the functions to be run at a particular time. Maybe this code will help you understand my question `def time():

    current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
    while current_time == '2019-03-18T19:37':
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

        test_1()    

    while current_time == '2019-03-18T19:38':
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('GMT')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

        test_2()`